# Deploy NextJS on Linux server

Tags: npm, next.js, yarnpkg, pm2

I'm just having a hell of a time trying to get a NextJS app running on a standard Linux server.

I've added this command:`NODE_ENV=production node server.js` under `npm run prod_start`, and that runs okay - terminal says:
`Ready on http://localhost:3000`. Great.

If I run the same with PM2:
`pm2 start npm --name "thing" -- prod_start`, it "works" insofar as there are no errors, but it just... does nothing. The process is running, PM2 is running, Apache is running, the app just does nothing.

Has anyone encountered something like this before? All the documentation for deployment just tries to get you to use 'ZEIT Now', which I don't want to do. I can't find any other meaningful documentation.

Answer (score 0):

- Does `pm ls` show any running Node processes?
- What do you mean by "does nothing"?
- Did you run `npm run build` first? (sorry had to ask :-D)
- Not 100% sure on syntax, does this work?

```
pm2 start --name "thing" npm -- run prod_start
```